# Sort strings containing numbers, chars and ponctuations in ”human readable order”

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream, human-readable

Assuming a list has the following entries:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A0", "A1", "A2", "A11", "A01", "A001", "A.1", "A-1", 
"a1", "a2", "a 1", "B1", "B2", "0A", "001", "1A", "10A", "10-A", "10.A", "A&B");
```

I'm using the code bellow to sort my list and obtain the following result :

```
[001, 0A, 1A, 10A, 10-A, 10.A, A0, A001, A01, A1, A2, A11, A-1, A&B, a 1, a1, a2, a11, B1, B2]
```

but the actual result is :

```
[001, 0A, 10A, 10-A, 10.A, 1A, A0, A001, A01, A1, A.1, A-1, A11, A2, A&B, B1, B2, a1, a 1, a2]
```

Which is not the expected sort order.

```
list = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(string -> string.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}0-9]", "")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Are there variants of the sorting algorithm that would

1. ignore anything that is not a letter or digit (i.e. ignore spaces and punctuation)
2. sort numbers in ”human order” (ex : Avoid 10 from appearing before 1 and 11 from appearing before 2 etc..)

?

Comment: 1. should be fine with your replace code, might need additions 2. youll have to write your own comparator: split number groups and letter groups, compare numbers as numbers, letters as usual, and numbers as lower(before) than letters

Comment: Please *precisely* define "human readable order". After you do that, you can write an algorithm.

Comment: @Sweeper, 1. Ignore anything that is not a letter or digit (i.e. ignore spaces and punctuation)
2. Sort numbers in ”human order” (ex : Avoid 10 from appearing before 1 and 11 from appearing before 2 etc..)

Comment: Your question/comment does not provide sufficient detail to accomplish this. `"001"  > "00011"` as strings, but `001 == 00001` as integers because leading zeroes don't affect the result. When you compare strings you are doing it lexically, To do otherwise requires you to split each token into its numeric and string counterparts. But that creates other problems since you need to know when an `int` comes before or after a string and that could result in comparing unlike types during the sort. Bottom line is that you are going to need a lot more logic in your comparator to accomplish this.